# Boot problem with grub; Arch Linux, Xen, Dom0

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub2, xen

After installing Arch I installed grub with these commands:

```
pacman -S grub
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=grub --recheck
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Now the grub menu appears and I can choose Arch Linux.
However, when I choose to boot in Arch Linux via grub I am greeted with this:

```
Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view 
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to try again
to boot into default mode.

Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.
see sulogin(8) man page for more details.

Press Enter to continue.
Pressing enter results into the same message with the added line:
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory (g-io-error-quark, 1)
```

My EFI boot menu still works fine, so I'm still able to login to Xen.

I have also notice a failed message when trying to boot into Arch Linux:

```
[Failed] Failed to mount /proc xen.
```

ls /boot

```
$ ls -lah
total 28M
drwxr-xr-x 5 rogier rogier  16K okt 31 13:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 rogier rogier  16K jan  1  1970 ..
drwxr-xr-x 5 rogier rogier  16K okt 31 13:18 EFI
drwxr-xr-x 6 rogier rogier  16K okt 31 13:18 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 rogier rogier  17M okt 31 13:18 initramfs-linux-fallback.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 rogier rogier 3,4M okt 31 13:18 initramfs-linux.img
drwxr-xr-x 3 rogier rogier  16K okt 31 13:18 loader
-rw-r--r-- 1 rogier rogier 4,1M okt 31 13:18 vmlinuz-linux
-rw-r--r-- 1 rogier rogier 2,0M okt 31 13:18 xen-4.5.1.efi
-rw-r--r-- 1 rogier rogier 850K okt 31 13:18 xen-4.5.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 rogier rogier  192 okt 31 13:18 xen.cfg
```

ls /boot/grub

```
$ ls -lah
total 160K
drwxr-xr-x 6 rogier rogier  16K okt 31 13:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 rogier rogier  16K okt 31 13:18 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 rogier rogier  16K okt 31 13:18 fonts
-rw-r--r-- 1 rogier rogier 6,7K okt 31 13:18 grub.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 rogier rogier 6,7K okt 31 13:18 grub.cfg.example
-rw-r--r-- 1 rogier rogier 1,0K okt 31 13:18 grubenv
drwxr-xr-x 2 rogier rogier  16K okt 31 13:18 locale
drwxr-xr-x 3 rogier rogier  16K okt 31 13:18 themes
drwxr-xr-x 2 rogier rogier  32K okt 31 13:18 x86_64-efi
```

lsblk -f

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                      
|-sda1 vfat         FF2C-B8A3                            /boot
|-sda2 btrfs        b3f4f40f-a8a1-4438-a187-dc02f2104340 /
|-sda3 swap         7d91962c-9eba-4fb2-b198-3a91c681e4f3 [SWAP]
`-sda4 btrfs        986d54c0-878d-4d18-843a-9245ee6d8be5
```

/boot/grub/grub.cfg

http://pastebin.archlinux.fr/1690052

Due to low reputation points, I can only post one link.
All numbers are archlinux pastebin links like the one above.

journalctl -k -b -1 (Arch Linux boot in grub)

1690454 (part 1)

1690455 (part 2)

1690453 (warnings and errors only)

journalctl -k -b -1 (Xen boot in grub)

1690410 (part 1)

1690411 (part 2)

1690452 (warnings and errors only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem kind of solved, good enough:

I deleted the line:

```
none /proc/xen xenfs defaults 0 0
```

in /etc/fstab

And I changed the Xen setup in grub.cfg to simply 'exit' so it would exit into the EFI boot menu.